# Android Live data

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, android-livedata

I have a parameter like

```
public class CounterTableDO extends ViewModel{
private LiveData<Double> _score;

@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = TypeConverter.class)
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "score")
    public LiveData<Double> getScore() {
        return _score;
    }
}
```

I want to detect any changes in AWS DynamoDB storage to be reflected over here.
I have been through 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.ArbitraryDataMapping.html

Under the TypeConverter class I have overridden 2 methods
First method converts object to String.
and second method is supposed to do the opposite.

```
public class TypeConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String,CounterTableDO> {
    @Override
    public String convert(CounterTableDO object) {
        CounterTableDO doubleLiveData=(CounterTableDO)object;
        String liveDataString=null;
        try
        {
            if(doubleLiveData!=null)
            {
                liveDataString=String.format("%s", doubleLiveData.getScore());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.toString();
        }
        return liveDataString;
    }

    @Override
    public CounterTableDO unconvert(String s) {

        CounterTableDO counterTableDO=new CounterTableDO();
        return counterTableDO;
        try{
            if((s!=null)&&(s.length()!=0)){
                String[] data=s.split("x");
                Double d =Double.parseDouble(data[0].trim());
                counterTableDO.setScore(d);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

But in unconvert method I'm unable to setScore of counterTableDO object using the instruction
counterTableDO.setScore(d);

This throws an error stating
"setScore (android.arch.lifecycle.livedata in CounterTableDO cannot be applied to java.lang.Double)"

Any idea how can we map Android LiveData to AWS pre-defined type?

Answer (score 0):

> DynamoDB supports the following primitive data types and primitive
> wrapper classes.
>
> String
>
> Boolean, boolean
>
> Byte, byte
>
> Date (as ISO_8601 millisecond-precision string, shifted to UTC)
>
> Calendar (as ISO_8601 millisecond-precision string, shifted to UTC)
>
> Long, long
>
> Integer, int
>
> Double, double
>
> Float, float
>
> BigDecimal
>
> BigInteger

android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData is not one of these types, so you can't just expect DynamoDBMapper to know how to handle it.

You will need to write a custom type convertor. Have a look at this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.ArbitraryDataMapping.html